# jQuery listener for click not working after div update

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an issue with a jQuery .click()

I have a div with a list of data inside of it, and a button next to each item in the list.. This button, when pressed, adds the data to your row in a DB.

```
<div id="appointments">
Data... - <input type='submit' class='update_confirmed_button'>
Data... - <input type='submit' class='update_confirmed_button'>
Data... - <input type='submit' class='update_confirmed_button'>
Data... - <input type='submit' class='update_confirmed_button'>
Data... - <input type='submit' class='update_confirmed_button'>
</div>
```

When the submit button is clicked, an ajax call updates the div with a new list to choose from..

This is a very large approximation of my project, but it gets the point across for this question..

My problem is, once ajax updates the div with new info, the submit button is no longer hooked to the listener (even tho its the same id name, it wasnt there on load so it's not hooked)...

Considering I have to update the list after submit is pressed, how can I make sure the button will still be hooked to the click() even after the html is updated via ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you have the same element ids, if you are using `.click()`, once the DOM is updated, that click event won't be bonded anymore. Instead use `.on('click',function(){});` so the click event would be bonded to dynamically added elements as well.

Answer (score 3):

instead of using `.click` use

```
$('#appointments').on('click', '.update_confirmed_button', function() {
    // do stuff here;
});
```

works on elements that are newly added to the dom as well